# Send updates to specific channel without any form of trigger

Tags: python-telegram-bot

While events on my algorithm occur, I want to dispatch updates to a specific channel. My code looks something like this

```
def _create_telegram_dispatcher():
    """Start the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater("TOKEN")

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    # on non command i.e message - echo the message on Telegram
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, echo))

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()

def _run():
    broker = BROKER()

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(_client_thread(api))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    self._create_telegram_dispatcher()
    self._run()
```

So while the broker is running, if a condition is satisfied I would like my bot to send an update on the channel, without needing someone to talk to it first. What is the way to get access to the telegram bot from my initialized `Broker` class, and have it send a message to a specific channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you implemented the `BROKER` class yourself, you could add an argument `bot` to it and pass `updater.bot` to it. This would require you to rework `_create_telegram_dispatcher` a bit, i.e. don't directly call `updater.idle()` inside the function.

Alternatively, you can just instantiate a new `Bot` instance inside your broker.

Edit: Once you have a bot instance available, sending messages is as easy as `(self.)bot.send_message(…)` - see [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Introduction-to-the-API) for more details.

Comment: I guess creating a new instance inside each module that I want to use it from is the most reasonable option for now. How do I proactively send messages to channels or users though?